# Can't invoke a function with js

Tags: javascript, html, onkeyup

Here is my html and js:

```js
function calculateFun()
{
 var a = document.getElementById('a').value;
 var b = document.getElementById('b').value;
 var c = document.getElementById('c').value;
 var d = document.getElementById('d').value;
 var e = document.getElementById('e').value;
 
 var f = a*b;
 document.getElementById('f').value = f;
 var g = (f + (f*(d/100))).toFixed();
 document.getElementById('g').value = g;
 var h = ((1 -((a*c)/e))*100).toFixed();
 document.getElementById('h').value = h;
 
}
```

```html
<input type="number" id="a" onkeyup="calculateFun();" />
<input type="number" id="b" onkeyup="calculateFun();" />
<input type="number" id="c" value="100" />
<input type="number" id="d" value="50" />
<input type="number" id="e" onkeyup="calculateFun();" />
<br><br><p>******</p><br><br>
<input type="number" id="f" />
<input type="number" id="g" />
<input type="number" id="h" />
```

I tried this code in JSFIDDLE:
https://jsfiddle.net/1ex3b1sa/

but it is not working. also in my site, the function isn't invoked.
it is strange because, i can invoke other functions that i did, almost with the same way.

i tried changing to onclick, onkeypress or onkeydown, but can't see any results..

any ideas? maybe i have a typo? or maybe its a chrome problem?

Comment: Because your fiddle is set up wrong! Code is in the onload event. https://jsfiddle.net/zvrywbLr/

Comment: Look a little harder @mattytommo

Comment: In JSFiddle, you need to set your JavaScript wrap to ***"No wrap - in `<head>`"*** or else you'll get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateFun is not defined" error.

Comment: oh ok, tnks it worked. And in the original code, Do I need to put it between the head tags? because, i have a function between the body tags, and it is working fine..

Comment: For perf, unless the script actually need to run first, usually is best to put the script tag at end before the closing body tag since otherwise it's blocking.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In JSFiddle, you need to set your JavaScript wrap to ***"No wrap - in `<head>`"*** or else you'll get an "Uncaught ReferenceError: calculateFun is not defined" error.

[image]

Make sure that the function is here:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculateFun() {
                // ...
```

---

You could actually keep the function definition in the `onLoad` wrap and change:

```
function calculateFun() {
```

To this:

```
window.calculateFun = function() {
```

And it will work because you are adding your function as a static method to the browser's `Window`.

Answer (score 1):

On the left side of jsfiddle.net is a box with "Frameworks & Extensions".

In the second select box you have to select:

> No wrap - in <body>

or

> No wrap - in <head>

Then it will work. If you dont do that the function will not be defind and it will run just once (in the OnLoad Event).

Answer (score -2):

please learn jquery, its not that hard and will help you!

your fiddle in functioning jquery: https://jsfiddle.net/1ex3b1sa/3/

input-fields got class='calc'
and js:

```
$('.calc').keyup(function(){

var a = $('#a').val();
var b = $('#b').val();
var c = $('#c').val();
var d = $('#d').val();
var e = $('#e').val();

var f = a * b;
$('#f').val(f);

var g = (f + (f*(d/100))).toFixed();
$('#g').val(g);

var h = ((1 -((a*c)/e))*100).toFixed();
$('#h').val(h);

});
```

Comment: That introduces unnecesary overhead in the website/application, which can make a great hit on performance. Usualy you should just use what you need, so as long as he deals with simple stuff where using the external library will not save enough coding or bring in new and usefull features, plain is the way to go. Btw seems to me like he is just starting with JS so practice and experience is what he needs anyways.